# local variable 'submission' referenced before assignment

Tags: django, python-3.x

I encounter this error for my django project. my app is called "scoresubmission"
basially i have a feature in the website to allow user download report. 
So in my views.py file i have report function and import report.py file, where it shows how report is built
It shows the error happens in this line of code:

```
 submission=Submission.objects.get(month=month,year=reportyear,program=program)
```

Views.py

```
def report(request):    

    from scoresubmission.report import reportA, reportB, reportC
    reportType = request.POST["reportType"]
    reportYear = int(request.POST["reportYear"])

    if reportType == 'a':
        report_content = reportA(reportYear)
        response = HttpResponse(report_content, content_type="text/csv")
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'inline; filename=5SAuditYearlySummaryReport_%d.xlsx' %reportYear
```

report.py where it has the relevant code
for facility in facilities:
        worksheet.write(row,col,facility.name,facility_format)

```
    for i in range(12): # 12 months
        month=i+1
        programs=Program.objects.filter(facility_id=facility.id)
        avg_totalscore=0
        count=1
        for program in programs:
            print(program)
            try:

                submission=Submission.objects.get(month=month,year=reportyear,program=program)
                print(submission)
                avg_score=Result.objects.filter(submission=submission).aggregate(Avg('NewScore'))
                #print avg_score.get('NewScore__avg')
                avg_totalscore=(avg_totalscore + avg_score.get('NewScore__avg'))/count
                count=count+1
            except submission.DoesNotExist:
                pass

                #print avg_totalscore
        if avg_totalscore!=0:
            worksheet.write(row,i+3,avg_totalscore,red_format)
        else:
            worksheet.write(row,i+3,'-',red_format)
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\Users\CHLOZHAO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
>       response = get_response(request)
>     File "C:\Users\CHLOZHAO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 115, in _get_response
>       response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
>     File "C:\Users\CHLOZHAO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 113, in _get_response
>       response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
>     File "C:\Users\CHLOZHAO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\decorators.py", line 21, in _wrapped_view
>       return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
>     File "C:\D Drive\5S Audit Website\my5saudit\scoresubmission\views.py", line 185, in report
>       report_content = reportA(reportYear)
>     File "C:\D Drive\5S Audit Website\my5saudit\scoresubmission\report.py", line 79, in reportA
>       except submission.DoesNotExist:
>   UnboundLocalError: local variable 'submission' referenced before assignment

Answer (score 0):

In your `except` you need to refer to the *class* `Submission`, *not* the object, since it does not *per se* exists at that time:

```
try:
    submission=Submission.objects.get(month=month,year=reportyear,program=program)
    print(submission)
    avg_score=Result.objects.filter(submission=submission).aggregate(Avg('NewScore'))
    #print avg_score.get('NewScore__avg')
    avg_totalscore=(avg_totalscore + avg_score.get('NewScore__avg'))/count
    count=count+1
except Submission.DoesNotExist:  # reference to the class, not the object
    pass
```

If `Sibmission.objects.get(..)` fails, then the `submission` variable is never assigned, and hence `submission.DoesNotExist` makes no sense.

You acutally should *never* use the object, and always use the model class itself to refer to the `DoesNotExist` exception class.